# Java script to calculate quiz result from radio buttons and ignore text fields

Tags: javascript, textfield, radiobuttonlist

I am creating a test where the results are calculated and given a percentage. It displays the correct answers at the bottom. The results can then be emailed back to me. The below code worked.Excuse the layout, I'm very new to this.

```
<html><head><title></title>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<link href="testpageCSS.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<script language="JavaScript">
<!--

var numQues = 4;
var numChoi = 4;

var answers = new Array(4);
answers[0] = "33v 1A";
answers[1] = "Climbs from between 8 -12v up to battery Voltage";
answers[2] = "Main power relay stuck open";
answers[3] = "2 Meters";

function getScore(form) {
var score = 0;
var currElt;
var currSelection;

for (i=0; i<numQues; i++) {
currElt = i*numChoi;
for (j=0; j<numChoi; j++) {
  currSelection = form.elements[currElt + j];
  if (currSelection.checked) {
    if (currSelection.value == answers[i]) {
      score++;
      break;
    }
  }
}
}

score = Math.round(score/numQues*100);
form.percentage.value = score + "%";

var correctAnswers = "";
for (i=1; i<=numQues; i++) {
correctAnswers += i + ". " + answers[i-1] + "\r\n";
}
form.solutions.value = correctAnswers;

}

// -->
</script>

</head>

<body>

<div id="centerTOP">

<h1>  HCA001</h1>

</div>



<div id="center">



<form name="quiz" method="post" action="mailto:myemail"enctype="text/plain">    

<h2>First name:</h2>
<input type="text" name="Firstname" value="" style="color: #000000;"  
background-color: #d9d9d9;">
<h2>Last name:</h2>

<input type="text" name="Lastname" value="" style="color: #000000;    background-color: #d9d9d9;">
<h2>Trade Partner:</h2>

<input type="text" name="Trade Partner" value="" style="color: #000000; background-color: #d9d9d9;">
<br><br><br>




<p>

<h2>1. What is the output Voltage and Current of the  Charger?</h2><br>
<input type="radio" name="q1" value="24v 1A">24v 1A<br>
<input type="radio" name="q1" value="33v 5A">33v 5A<br>
<input type="radio" name="q1" value="24v 5A">24v 5A<br>
<input type="radio" name="q1" value="33v 1A">33v 1A<br><br><br>
<p>

<h2>2. If you were checking the communications voltage for any of the   powered options (Auto Hinge, Powered Footplate or Powered Swivel)what would you expect to see?</h2><br>
<input type="radio" name="q2" value="Climbs from between 8 -12v up to battery Voltage">Climbs from between 8 -12v up to battery Voltage<br>
<input type="radio" name="q2" value="Climbs from 4v to Battery Voltage">Climbs from 4v to Battery Voltage<br>
<input type="radio" name="q2" value="24v">24v<br>
<input type="radio" name="q2" value="33v">33v<br><br><br>
<p>

<h2>3. What does it mean if fault code 'E' is displayed on the diagnostic display?</h2><br>
<input type="radio" name="q3" value="Main power relay stuck open">Main power relay stuck open<br>
<input type="radio" name="q3" value="Main power relay welded closed">Main power relay welded closed<br>
<input type="radio" name="q3" value="The main power relay closed early">The main power relay closed early<br>
<input type="radio" name="q3" value="Error">Error<br><br><br>
<p>

<h2>4. What is the minimum length of a Slidetrack rail?</h2><br>
<input type="radio" name="q4" value="2 Meters">2 Meters<br>
<input type="radio" name="q4" value="2.1 Meters">2.1 Meters<br>
<input type="radio" name="q4" value="2.2 Meters">2.2 Meters<br>
<input type="radio" name="q4" value="2.5 Meters">2.5 Meters<br><br><br>
<p>

<input type="button" value="Get score" onClick="getScore(this.form)"><br>     <br><br>

<font face="arial" color="#5f5f5f">Score = <input type=text size=15 name="percentage" style="color: #000000; background-color: #d9d9d9;"><br><br>
Correct answers:</font><br>
<textarea name="solutions" wrap="virtual" rows="10" cols="40" style="color: #000000; background-color: #d9d9d9;"></textarea>
<br><br>

<input type="submit" value="Send Form">

<input type="reset" value="Clear Form">


</form>

</div>

</body></html>
```

Then I needed to add the text fields as below to enter test users details, which I have added to the submitable form. Now the script tries to calculate the score using the text fields aswell, which gives an incorrect result.Any idea how to alter the script to only look at the radio button inputs?

```
<h2>First name:</h2>
<input type="text" name="Firstname" value="" style="color: #000000; background-color: #d9d9d9;">

<h2>Last name:</h2>

<input type="text" name="Lastname" value="" style="color: #000000; background-color: #d9d9d9;">
<h2>Trade Partner:</h2>

<input type="text" name="Trade Partner" value="" style="color: #000000; background-color: #d9d9d9;">
```

Comment: Add a class to the elements that are part of the quiz, and use that instead of `form.elements`

Comment: You're accessing the form elements by index. You added three items to the element list, prior to the ones you want to access. If this was an array, like say, `var a = [1,2,3];` and you were getting those by `for (var i = 0, i < 3; i++) { var b = a[i]; }` and then you added items to the array, and made it `var a = [5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3];`, how would you alter your for loop to ensure you're still getting the same results?

Comment: Also, as an FYI, you have an extra double quote in the style attribute of the First Name input.

Comment: You've already named all the radio button elements -- why could you simply not use the document.getElementsByName() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set type property radio and get them using

```
var inputs = form1.elements;
 for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; ++i) {
        if (inputs[i].type == 'radio') {

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a class to the elements that should be scored, and then iterate over those elements.

Here is a demo:  https://jsfiddle.net/zephyr_hex/1o9u19be/

**JS**

```
var myBtn = document.getElementById('getScore');
myBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('quiz');
  for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
    if (elems[i].checked) {
      console.log(elems[i].value);
      //add your scoring logic here.  elems[i].value is the selected value
    }
  }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<form name="quiz" method="post" action="mailto:myemail" enctype="text/plain">
  <h2>First name:</h2>
  <input type="text" name="Firstname" value="" style="color: #000000; background-color: #d9d9d9;">
  <h2>Last name:</h2>
  <input type="text" name="Lastname" value="" style="color: #000000;    background-color: #d9d9d9;">
  <h2>Trade Partner:</h2>
  <input type="text" name="Trade Partner" value="" style="color: #000000; background-color: #d9d9d9;">
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <p>
    <h2>1. What is the output Voltage and Current of the  Charger?</h2>
    <br>
    <input class="quiz" type="radio" name="q1" value="24v 1A">24v 1A
    <br>
    <input class="quiz" type="radio" name="q1" value="33v 5A">33v 5A
    <br>
    <input class="quiz" type="radio" name="q1" value="24v 5A">24v 5A
    <br>
    <input class="quiz" type="radio" name="q1" value="33v 1A">33v 1A
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <p>

      <h2>2. If you were checking the communications voltage for any of the   powered options (Auto Hinge, Powered Footplate or Powered Swivel)what would you expect to see?</h2>
      <br>
      <input class="quiz" type="radio" name="q2" value="Climbs from between 8 -12v up to battery Voltage">Climbs from between 8 -12v up to battery Voltage
      <br>
      <input class="quiz" type="radio" name="q2" value="Climbs from 4v to Battery Voltage">Climbs from 4v to Battery Voltage
      <br>
      <input class="quiz" type="radio" name="q2" value="24v">24v
      <br>
      <input class="quiz" type="radio" name="q2" value="33v">33v
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <p>
        <h2>3. What does it mean if fault code 'E' is displayed on the diagnostic display?</h2>
        <br>
        <input class="quiz" type="radio" name="q3" value="Main power relay stuck open">Main power relay stuck open
        <br>
        <input class="quiz" type="radio" name="q3" value="Main power relay welded closed">Main power relay welded closed
        <br>
        <input class="quiz" type="radio" name="q3" value="The main power relay closed early">The main power relay closed early
        <br>
        <input class="quiz" type="radio" name="q3" value="Error">Error
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <p>

          <h2>4. What is the minimum length of a Slidetrack rail?</h2>
          <br>
          <input class="quiz" type="radio" name="q4" value="2 Meters">2 Meters
          <br>
          <input class="quiz" class="quiz" type="radio" name="q4" value="2.1 Meters">2.1 Meters
          <br>
          <input class="quiz" type="radio" name="q4" value="2.2 Meters">2.2 Meters
          <br>
          <input class="quiz" type="radio" name="q4" value="2.5 Meters">2.5 Meters
          <br>
          <br>
          <br>
          <p>

            <input id="getScore" type="button" value="Get score">
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>

            <font face="arial" color="#5f5f5f">Score = <input type=text size=15 name="percentage" style="color: #000000; background-color: #d9d9d9;"><br><br>
Correct answers:</font>
            <br>
            <textarea name="solutions" wrap="virtual" rows="10" cols="40" style="color: #000000; background-color: #d9d9d9;"></textarea>
            <br>
            <br>

            <input type="submit" value="Send Form">
            <input type="reset" value="Clear Form">
</form>
```